# Eclipse Team Syncronization Perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective

Our team has about 8 eclipse projects and the Source Control we are using is Star Team.I can open these projects from the Java browsing perspective in eclipse ,but i cannot find these projects in the Team Synchronization perspective.The version of eclipse is 3.6.1.Please let me know in case some other information needs to be provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the [StarTeam plugin for Eclipse](http://www.borland.com/downloads/download_starteam_integrations.html)? Don't rely on perspectives these are just accumulations of different views (being on one perspective and adding/removing/shuffling views around would memorize it for you next time you return on this perspective). I am sure there's going to be a `Window` > `Show View` > `"Relevant StarTeam view"` after you install the relevant plugin.